# parallel removal of elements from an array

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to do a parallel version of [STL remove_if](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/remove_if/). What I did is to create a counter in the global memory, and let each thread work on one element. If that element is not equal to the key, then it will be copied to the result array, with an index determined by the counter through an atomic add. Is there any better alternative to avoid frequent atomic operations?

I've found that the thrust library also has a remove_if, but I feel very confused about the source code located in "thrust\detail\backend\cpp\remove.h" directory:

```
template<typename ForwardIterator,
     typename InputIterator,
     typename Predicate>
ForwardIterator remove_if(ForwardIterator first,
                        ForwardIterator last,
                        InputIterator stencil,
                        Predicate pred)
{
// advance iterators until pred(*stencil) is true or we reach the end of input
while(first != last && !bool(pred(*stencil)))
{
    ++first;
    ++stencil;
}

if(first == last)
    return first;

// result always trails first 
ForwardIterator result = first;

++first;
++stencil;

while(first != last)
{
    if(!bool(pred(*stencil)))
    {
        *result = *first;
        ++result;
    }
    ++first;
    ++stencil;
}

return result;
}
```

Isn't this performing the element removal in sequence?

Thanks for any suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you have a compelling reason to roll your own implementation, I recommend you just use Thrust remove_if().  Thrust is modeled on the STL and if your requirements for generality are similar, you will wind up writing code that looks very similar to the Thrust source code.

If the performance of Thrust isn't satisfactory, the Thrust community (including the principal authors) might have good suggestions on how to formulate your code for better performance.

Failing that - if you have a vertical application and Thrust isn't fast enough - roll a scan-based implementation as a last resort.  The one-line summary of the algorithm is to do a parallel prefix sum ("scan") on the inverse of the predicate - the output index of elements you want to keep is then specified by the corresponding element of the scan.

Comment: I forgot to mention where you can engage the Thrust users community: http://groups.google.com/group/thrust-users

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Using the prefix sum is a great idea!