# Removing elements from CUDA array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, graph, cuda

**Context**

I'm trying to implement Boruvka MST algorithm using CUDA, but it's not necessary to understand the algorithm at all to help me here.

**Problem**

So, let me describe the problem: I have a graph, stored in list of edges format (an array of edges, each edge is represented with 2 adjacent vertex IDs and it's weight).

But, (it is very important!) to optimize accesses into device memory I store the edges not as a single array of structs, but as three separate arrays:

- int *src_ids
- int *dst_ids
- float *weights

To access single edge one can just iterate with the same index to this arrays:

- src_ids[i]
- dst_ids[i]
- weights[i]

Now, when I have described the data format, here is the problem

I want to remove from these three arrays elements(edges) with the following conditions:

**1)** if src_id[i] == dst_id[i], then remove the i-th edge

**2)** if src_id[i] != dst_id[i], but there is another edge j with the same src_id[j] and dst_id[j], but with smaller weight[j], than remove i-th edge

In other words I want to:

- remove the edges
- connecting the same vertices
- and duplicate non-minimal edges

The first is simple: I can use thrust::remove_if or scan as described here [parallel removal of elements from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328357/parallel-removal-of-elements-from-an-array), to remove the edges with the same ids. (I have already implemented the second variant with the scan).

But I have failed to implement the second part, the removal of duplicate edges. I have one idea, but not sure if this approach is efficient at all. Let me describe it.

First of all we will reorder(or sort) this three arrays in the following way:

- first sort the edges by the first (src_id) ID.
- Then sort the edges with equal first ID by the second (dst_id) id.
- Finally, sort the edges with both equal ids by their weights.

When all the edges are sorted this way, it's relatively easy to remove the duplicate non-minimal edges:

- we just look at the previous edge (i-1)-th,
- and if it has the same ids, but lesser weight, mark current edge for removal.
- Then we need just to apply scan, similar as for the (1 src_id[i] == dst_id[i]) condition.

**Question***

But the problem is that I don't know how to sort three arrays this way efficiently. (probably I can use thrust::sort on converted data, single array of structs, but it seems it will be very slow and it's better not to remove duplicate edges at all)

Or probably someone can advice the better way to remove duplicate edges without sorting them this way.

Thank you for reading this, any advice appreciated!

Comment: Note that this: *First of all we will reorder(or sort) this three arrays in the following way: first sort the edges by the first (src_id) ID. Then sort the edges with equal first ID by the second (dst_id) id. Finally, sort the edges with both equal ids by their weights.* can be done with a **single** call to `thrust::sort`.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29597224/sorting-packed-vertices-with-thrust/29599043#29599043) is a worked example of a thrust sort based on multiple criteria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily sort multiple vectors in one `thrust::sort` call by using a [`thrust::zip_iterator`](https://thrust.github.io/doc/classthrust_1_1zip__iterator.html).

The main idea is:

```
auto z = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_src_ids.begin(),d_dst_ids.begin(), d_weights.begin()));
thrust::sort(z,z+N);
```

This will sort the three vectors first by the first vector, then by the second, then by the third.

The following code shows how to use this in a fully worked out example. It uses a custom functor (copied from [`thrust::detail`](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/detail/range/head_flags.h)) to do the `remove_if` step in a single call without having to store intermediate results.

```
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/remove.h>

#define PRINTER(name) print(#name, (name))
template <template <typename...> class V, typename T, typename ...Args>
void print(const char* name, const V<T,Args...> & v)
{
    std::cout << name << ":\t";
    thrust::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(std::cout, "\t"));
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

// copied from https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/thrust/detail/range/head_flags.h

#include <thrust/iterator/transform_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/zip_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/iterator/counting_iterator.h>
#include <thrust/tuple.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>

template<typename RandomAccessIterator,
         typename BinaryPredicate = thrust::equal_to<typename thrust::iterator_value<RandomAccessIterator>::type>,
         typename ValueType = bool,
         typename IndexType = typename thrust::iterator_difference<RandomAccessIterator>::type>
  class head_flags
{
  // XXX WAR cudafe issue
  //private:
  public:
    struct head_flag_functor
    {
      BinaryPredicate binary_pred; // this must be the first member for performance reasons
      IndexType n;

      typedef ValueType result_type;

      __host__ __device__
      head_flag_functor(IndexType n)
        : binary_pred(), n(n)
      {}

      __host__ __device__
      head_flag_functor(IndexType n, BinaryPredicate binary_pred)
        : binary_pred(binary_pred), n(n)
      {}

      template<typename Tuple>
      __host__ __device__ __thrust_forceinline__
      result_type operator()(const Tuple &t)
      {
        const IndexType i = thrust::get<0>(t);

        // note that we do not dereference the tuple's 2nd element when i <= 0
        // and therefore do not dereference a bad location at the boundary
        return (i == 0 || !binary_pred(thrust::get<1>(t), thrust::get<2>(t)));
      }
    };

    typedef thrust::counting_iterator<IndexType> counting_iterator;

  public:
    typedef thrust::transform_iterator<
      head_flag_functor,
      thrust::zip_iterator<thrust::tuple<counting_iterator,RandomAccessIterator,RandomAccessIterator> >
    > iterator;

    __host__ __device__
    head_flags(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
      : m_begin(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(thrust::counting_iterator<IndexType>(0), first, first - 1)),
                                                head_flag_functor(last - first))),
        m_end(m_begin + (last - first))
    {}

    __host__ __device__
    head_flags(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last, BinaryPredicate binary_pred)
      : m_begin(thrust::make_transform_iterator(thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(thrust::counting_iterator<IndexType>(0), first, first - 1)),
                                                head_flag_functor(last - first, binary_pred))),
        m_end(m_begin + (last - first))
    {}

    __host__ __device__
    iterator begin() const
    {
      return m_begin;
    }

    __host__ __device__
    iterator end() const
    {
      return m_end;
    }

    template<typename OtherIndex>
    __host__ __device__
    typename iterator::reference operator[](OtherIndex i)
    {
      return *(begin() + i);
    }

  private:
    iterator m_begin, m_end;
};

template<typename RandomAccessIterator>
__host__ __device__
head_flags<RandomAccessIterator>
  make_head_flags(RandomAccessIterator first, RandomAccessIterator last)
{
  return head_flags<RandomAccessIterator>(first, last);
}

int main()
{
  const int N = 6;
  int src_ids[] = {3,1,2,2,3,3};
  int dst_ids[] = {2,2,3,3,1,1};
  float weights[] = {1,2,8,4,5,6};

  thrust::device_vector<int> d_src_ids(src_ids,src_ids+N);
  thrust::device_vector<int> d_dst_ids(dst_ids,dst_ids+N);
  thrust::device_vector<float> d_weights(weights,weights+N); 

  std::cout << "--- initial values ---" << std::endl;
  PRINTER(d_src_ids);
  PRINTER(d_dst_ids);
  PRINTER(d_weights);


  auto z = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_src_ids.begin(),d_dst_ids.begin(), d_weights.begin()));

  thrust::sort(z,z+N);

  std::cout << "--- after sort ---" << std::endl;
  PRINTER(d_src_ids);
  PRINTER(d_dst_ids);
  PRINTER(d_weights);

  auto z2 = thrust::make_zip_iterator(thrust::make_tuple(d_src_ids.begin(),d_dst_ids.begin()));


  auto t = make_head_flags(z2,z2+N);
  using namespace thrust::placeholders;
  auto end = thrust::remove_if(z,z+N, t.begin(), !_1);
  int new_size = thrust::get<0>(end.get_iterator_tuple()) - d_src_ids.begin();

  d_src_ids.resize(new_size);
  d_dst_ids.resize(new_size);
  d_weights.resize(new_size);

  std::cout << "--- after remove_if ---" << std::endl;
  PRINTER(d_src_ids);
  PRINTER(d_dst_ids);
  PRINTER(d_weights);


  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
--- initial values ---
d_src_ids:  3   1   2   2   3   3   
d_dst_ids:  2   2   3   3   1   1   
d_weights:  1   2   8   4   5   6   
--- after sort ---
d_src_ids:  1   2   2   3   3   3   
d_dst_ids:  2   3   3   1   1   2   
d_weights:  2   4   8   5   6   1   
--- after remove_if ---
d_src_ids:  1   2   3   3   
d_dst_ids:  2   3   1   2   
d_weights:  2   4   5   1
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this example helps a lot.